# How to update or insert to import using typescript compiler api?

Tags: typescript, abstract-syntax-tree

I using `transform` function from typescript compiler api to change my code.

This function is recursive and visit each node.

When I found a `StringLiteral` of `foo` I want to add `foo` to import where `my-lib` like this:

```
import { foo } from 'my-lib';
```

The code can have already import something else from `my-lib` like:

```
import { bar } from 'my-lib';
```

And I want to avoid this result (duplicate imports):

```
import { foo } from 'my-lib';
import { bar } from 'my-lib';
```

The closest solution I was able to find is this:

```
const file = (node as ts.Node) as ts.SourceFile;
const update = ts.updateSourceFileNode(file, [
  ts.createImportDeclaration(
    undefined,
    undefined,
    ts.createImportClause(
      undefined,
      ts.createNamedImports([ts.createImportSpecifier(ts.createIdentifier("default"), ts.createIdentifier("salami"))])
    ),
    ts.createLiteral('salami')
  ),
  ...file.statements
]);
```

But the functions are deprecates. and I can't return `ts.createImportDeclaration` becuase I will get the `import` and not the code of `StringLiteral` of `foo`.

Is there a function say "update or insert y from x to the imports statements"?

The code I was able to do so far:

```
import * as ts from "typescript";

const code = `
console.log('foo');
`;

const node = ts.createSourceFile("x.ts", code, ts.ScriptTarget.Latest);

const printer = ts.createPrinter({ newLine: ts.NewLineKind.LineFeed });

export const upsertImport = (context) => (rootNode) => {
  const { factory } = context;

  function visit(node) {
    if (ts.isStringLiteral(node) && node.text === "foo") {
      // need to add: import { foo } from 'my-lib'; but how??
      console.log("need to add: import { foo } from my-lib; but how??");
    }

    return ts.visitEachChild(node, visit, context);
  }

  return ts.visitNode(rootNode, visit);
};

const result = ts.transform(node, [upsertImport]);

const transformedSourceFile = result.transformed[0];

const out = printer.printFile(transformedSourceFile);

console.log({ out });
```

[codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-pond-x2bi8?file=/src/index.js:0-819)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the visitor to walk the AST and store which members have been utilized without editing any nodes. Afterward (while still in the transform), you can find/upsert the `ImportDeclaration` on the `sourceFile` with which members have been accessed:

```
/**
 * Helper function for updating an import declaration statement with a new set of members
 * unhandled edge cases include:
 * existing `import "my-lib";`
 * existing `import * as myLib from "my-lib";
 */
const updateNamedImports = (factory: ts.NodeFactory, node: ts.ImportDeclaration, utilizedMembers: Set<string>): ts.ImportDeclaration => {
    // We're not using updateNamedImports since we've verified
    // which imports are actually being used already
    const namedImports = factory.createNamedImports(
        Array.from(utilizedMembers)
            .map(name =>
                factory.createImportSpecifier(
                    undefined,
                    factory.createIdentifier(name)
                )
            )
    )
    let importClause: ts.ImportClause;
    if (node.importClause && node.importClause.namedBindings) {
        importClause = factory.updateImportClause(
            node.importClause,
            node.importClause.isTypeOnly,
            node.importClause.name,
            namedImports
        );
    }
    else {
        importClause = factory.createImportClause(
            false,
            undefined,
            namedImports
        )
    }
    return factory.updateImportDeclaration(
        node,
        node.decorators,
        node.modifiers,
        importClause,
        node.moduleSpecifier
    );
}

/**
 * Main transform function
 */
const upsertImport: ts.TransformerFactory<ts.SourceFile> = (context) => (rootNode) => {
    const { factory } = context;

    const MY_LIB = "my-lib";

    // use a set to keep track of members which have been accessed,
    // and guarantee uniqueness
    const utilizedMembers = new Set<string>();
    // I ventured a guess you want to check more than just "foo"
    const availableMembers = new Set([ "foo", "bar", "baz" ]);

    // Find which imports you need
    function collectUtilizedMembers(node: ts.Node): ts.Node {
        if (ts.isStringLiteral(node) && availableMembers.has(node.text)) {
            utilizedMembers.add(node.text);
        }
        return ts.visitEachChild(node, collectUtilizedMembers, context);
    }

    // run your visitor which will fill up the `utilizedMembers` set.
    ts.visitNode(rootNode, collectUtilizedMembers);

    // find the existing import if it exists using findIndex
    // so we can splice it back into the existing statements
    const matchedImportIdx = rootNode.statements
        .findIndex(s => ts.isImportDeclaration(s)
            && (s.moduleSpecifier as ts.StringLiteral).text === MY_LIB
        );

    // if it exists, update it
    if (matchedImportIdx !== -1) {
        const node = rootNode.statements[matchedImportIdx] as ts.ImportDeclaration;
        // update source file with updated import statement
        return factory.updateSourceFile(rootNode, [
            ...rootNode.statements.slice(0, matchedImportIdx),
            updateNamedImports(factory, node, utilizedMembers),
            ...rootNode.statements.slice(matchedImportIdx + 1)
        ]);
    }
    else {
        // if it doesn't exist, create it and insert it at
        // the top of the source file
        return factory.updateSourceFile(rootNode, [
            factory.createImportDeclaration(
                undefined,
                undefined,
                factory.createImportClause(
                    false,
                    undefined,
                    factory.createNamedImports(
                        Array.from(utilizedMembers).map(name =>
                            factory.createImportSpecifier(
                                undefined,
                                factory.createIdentifier(name)
                            )
                        )
                    )
                ),
                factory.createStringLiteral(MY_LIB)
            ),
            ...rootNode.statements
        ]);
    }
};
```

Because this code checks which members are actually utilized, it replaces the existing `namedImports`. If you want to preserve the existing ones (even if they haven't been used or are not included in `availableMembers`, you can merge the `utilizedMembers` set with the existing `importDeclaration.importClause.namedImports` array in `updateNamedImports`. This also doesn't handle the case of existing statements `import * as myLib from "my-lib";`/`import "my-lib";`, but that should be easy to add depending on how you want to handle it.

Comment: Is it possible to use string templates instead of ts factory functions?

Comment: This is great, thanks. I'm writing some code where I need to add multiple imports while fixing missing imports for two specific libraries and this got me most of the way there.